# Sniffing the Router for Packets

Tags: wireshark, sniffing

I have used WireShark software to sniff my Network Interface. What if i wanted to sniff the router that what other computers on the network are doing? Is there any way to do that? 
Computers are connecting through WiFi.

Answer (score 2):

The router is a bit of a red-herring in the question as it is unlikely to have the ability to mirror the wifi data out to your PC. The best you could do with the router would probably be to put your PC between the router and the internet and sniff that traffic, but you would miss out on any traffic that stayed within the LAN.

A better approach might be to feed Wireshark the wifi passphrase and let it decrypt over the air. A guide to that is here:

http://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11